# python - compare two lists

Tags: python, compare

I'm learning python and trying to create a movie collection for my own use using web.py .

I have two lists

```
movies_all = ["abc","xyz","opq"]
movies_watched = ["xyz","pqr","cba"]
```

What I want to do is Print all rows of movies_all in the final output.
Such that If there is a match in list movies_watched, output Yes or No. For example, in above only "xyz" is common.

Preferably the output should be in a single data type, for example "list of lists" or dictionary or list of tuples, etc.
The intention is to display the output in an html table like the one below.

Output:

```
================
Movies| Watched |
------|---------|
abc   |No       |
xyz   |Yes      |
opq   |No       |
```

The table in output is only for improving readability and is actually not required.

I have tried this but not able to output desired result

```
 matches=[]
 print "start comparing"
 for item_a in movies_all:
     for item_b in movies_watched:
         if item_a == item_b:
             matches.append(item_a)
             matches.append("Yes")
             #result=zip(movies_all,matches) -> Tried this but not getting desired output

 for i in range(4):
     print("%s, %s" % (movies_all[i],matches))
```

Comment: You should post your own attempt at coding this, otherwise your question will attract downvotes. Hint: to do this efficiently, `movies_watched` should be a `set`.

Comment: Use the answer that someone posted and then do: import pandas as pd, d = {'movies':movies}, df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for informing, practically my first post, added my failed attempt of the code

Comment: @Bharat use the answer and my comment on the answer and done

Comment: @sera I want to use panda as a last resort, looking for something simple and easy

Comment: In your example code what is `a`, used in `print("%s, %s" % (a[i],matches))`. There's no definition for it.

Comment: Also, your loop creates `result`, but you don't use it for anything. But thanks for posting some code. Your final `for` loop loops 4 times, but there are only 3 movies in the list, so the code will crash with an `IndexError` on the last loop.

Comment: @IljaEverilä PM 2Rings Sorry about that, have been trying many things, fixed the description.
Although bennett-brown's Answer seems apt and very simple, I'm going to accept this answer since this is closest.
Thanks you all for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through one list with `for...in...` and compare to the other list with `in`. Build your dictionary by creating an empty dictionary and assigning a value to each new key. In  your example, you'll have a key for each item in movies_all.

```
movies={}
for movie in movies_all:
    if movie in movies_watched:
        movies[movie] = "yes"
    else:
        movies[movie] = "no"
```

Comment: @Bharat Then do: import pandas as pd, d = {'watched':movies}, df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Comment: @bennett-brown Thanks this looks like what I was looking for. I was able to get the desired output
    >>> for key, value in movies.iteritems():
         print ("%s %s" % (key,value))

 
xyz yes
abc no
opq no

Comment: Is it possible to retain the order of movies_all, since I noticed the order changes when printing the values. For example with bigger movies_all list the order is different from original:
qwe no
xyz yes
abc no
124 no
opq no

Comment: A `dict` is unordered – for the time being. Use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). And move from Python 2 to 3, if you're just starting with Python. Better to learn the current version that does not have an end-of-life looming.

Comment: @Bharat I wouldn't bother with a `dict` for this, I'd use a list of tuples, eg `movies_watched = set(movies_watched); lst = [(u, ('No', 'Yes')[u in movies_watched]) for u in movies_all]`

Comment: @PM2Ring this outputs is in correct order, care to explain how it works?

Comment: @Bharat It's a list comprehension. Here's a slightly simpler version: `lst=[(u, u in movies_watched) for u in movies_all]`. That's equivalent to `lst=[]` `for u in movies_all:` `lst.append((u, u in movies_watched))`. Sorry, it's not easy posting multi-line Python code in comments, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @PM2Ring This is clear and helpful, thanks. I would have upvoted this comment if I could.